# twitter-bootstrap .thumbnail/.pull-left and blockquote overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am sure there is a simple solution to it.. but I have some markup that is overlapping.  I have a img.pull-left and a blockquote.  The img is currently sitting in between the grey left border and the block quote.  Markup is pretty simple:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="entry-content clearfix"> 
           <a class="pull-left" href="#noop" title="The first post">
            <img width="70" height="47" src="logo-lw.png" class="inline attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="logo-lw"/>     
            </a>

            <blockquote>
                <p>Some Quote...</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/dykJD/)

Comment: What do you mean by "on top"? The text seem to render fine around the image. If this isn't expected what was?

Comment: @mbanzon There is a grey border that is to the left of the image, i need it on the right of it.

Comment: If you need the gray border to be on right, add class "pull-right":
 <blockquote class="pull-right">....</blockquote>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add inline-block to the blockquote:

```
blockquote{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is also a good use case for the [bootstrap media object](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#media).

Comment: I would use media if I could, but this is a template and I dont want to mess with it.  Any drawbacks on doing this globally?  Or can do I need to be more specific i.e. `[class='pull-left'] + blockquote`?

Comment: Yes, I would be more specific with the selector as you suggested so its not applied globally. better use of your example: `a.pull-left + blockquote`

Comment: Or restrict it even further so its only applied when inside entry-content: `.entry-content a.pull-left + blockquote`

Comment: Yea, i pasted the wrong one, my example is not using pull.. its using spanx and was a wild card selector [class*='span']